# Windows versus Mac specific fonts in Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, bounds

It turns out that the font as well as bounds I've used to create my GUI on my Mac are completely different than those of a Windows computer.

So the GUI on my Mac looks completely different than when run on a Windows computer.

Is there any way at all to fix this issue, while still using my preferred font?

Comment: Not unless your "preferred font" is either one that is installed on both of the OSes (think "Times New Roman", "Arial"), or you are free to distribute it along with your application. Is using images out of the question?

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).